# Worksheet_Change stops saving changes after certain limit

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Scope = "G9:H6127" ' monitoring area

    Static oData As New Dictionary
    Dim rCells As Range
    Dim oCell
    Dim dDelta

    Set rCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range(Scope))
    If Not rCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each oCell In rCells
            With oCell
                dDelta = oData(.Address)
                    .Offset(0, 60).Value = dDelta
                    oData(.Address) = .Value
            End With
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

I am trying to record changing in my sheet. My MAIN monitor area is G9:H69 but I needed 100 reading so I gave it the range G9:H6127 which completes 100. but it doesn't record any changes after cell G&H 3608. That means its only 50 readings.

I have tried everything I can do but didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need 100 reading"?

Comment: I think there is a limit. Try to display the address of rCells to see if the last row is 6127 or less. Also, try to run step by step to find where is the problem. If there is a limit, then it is better to write your cells in an array.